# Flutter: How do I calculate difference in 2 datetime values and add it all up

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: reportsCollection
      .where('userid', isEqualTo: auth.currentUser?.uid)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          QueryDocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
          return ListTile(
            //TODO sort not by id, sort by date desc/asce
            leading: Text(doc['time'].toString() +
                ' to ' +
                doc['time2'].toString()),
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  },
),
```

Hey guys I'm new here and I'm run into a wall. For my project, I'm entering data into Firebase database and displaying it back on my app via Streambuilder w/ ListTile. I want to calculate the difference between the 2 time values using [date time picker](https://pub.dev/packages/date_time_picker) in 24 hrs clock and add all the instances for an id up to show in a circular bar in [percent indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) package, there's like 20 different ids. The time values are linked to an id and they aren't shown chronologically, I'm not sure why a ListTile will suddenly appear in the middle. I have a similar thing for another page so this issue is for that page. I appreciate any help and thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use text use `Datetime.parse` after that get diffrence

Comment: Yeah I saw online how to do that, but I want to do that for the instances of an id and add it all up before showing the data in a circular graph.